# Reduced variants of stream ciphers

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, lightweight

What are "reduced variants" of stream ciphers and how do they relate to lightweight cryptography?

How do their internal states compare to those of non-reduced variants? Security aspects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware of reduced variants of Salsa20 (Salsa20/12 and Salsa20/8). These are variants of Salsa20 using reduced number of hashing rounds (12 and 8 instead of standard 20).

This is the same idea as reducing number of rounds of a block cipher - you get better performance by undermining security.

Comment: Is Bivium a reduced variant of Trivium?

Comment: @RomanVolkov [This paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/240.pdf) says that Bivium-A and Bivium-B are reduced versions of Trivium.